# How to use a value from another form that shares the same parent

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently working with 3 forms :

- One is a screenwide "background" with buttons that serve as a parent for both the other forms
- The second one is filled with a DataGridView and a button that opens the third one
- The third one has multiple textboxes

The goal is to select a row in the second one, then click the button and open the third one, that uses a SQL command to request info, using the first value in datagrid view as a `WHERE`

I wanted to use, in the Third form, `SecondForm.TheDataGridView.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString`, but it seems to be out of the Index

Here is my code :

- Parent to second one :

`Dim Sec As New SecondForm()
Sec.MdiParent = Me
Sec.Show()`

- Second one to third one :

`Dim ThirdOne As New ThirdForm()
ThirdOne.MdiParent = ParentForm
ThirdOne.Show()`

- Third one's SQL request as String

`Dim Request As String = "SELECT *, ForeignColumn FROM ADataBase " &
"INNER JOIN SecondTable ON ADatabase.ForeignKey = SecondTable.PrimaryKey " &
"WHERE ID = " & SecondForm.TheDataGridView.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString`

But I get the common error

> Index out of range

Comment: Override the constructor on the 3th form so you can pass information from the 2nd form to the 3th form. `Dim ThirdOne as New ThirdForm(somevalue)`

Comment: Try this `sec.TheDataGridView.SelectedRows(0)(0).Value.ToString`

Comment: preciousbetine : 'DataGridViewCell can't be indexed because it doesn't have a default value' (Translated from french)
GuidoG : Same error :(

Comment: can you show us the code you used to try my suggestion ? It cannot be the same error

Comment: Nevermind, I got the error 
`Base class 'Form' specified for class 'SecondForm' cannot be different from the base class 'SecondForm' of one of its other partial types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach, assuming you'll only ever have ONE instance of SecondForm in the MdiParent:

```
Public Class ThirdForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim second As SecondForm = GetSecondForm()
        If Not IsNothing(second) Then
            Debug.Print(second.TheDataGridView.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSecondForm() As SecondForm
        Dim second As SecondForm = Nothing
        For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiParent.MdiChildren
            If frm Is SecondForm Then
                second = DirectCast(frm, SecondForm)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return second
    End Function

End Class
```

If you're going to have more than one instance of SecondForm, and each ThirdForm should be "paired" with a specific instance, then pass a reference from one to the other as suggested by the others in the comments.

Comment: That worked pretty good ! I should have added that yes, there will be only one instance of each at a time. Thanks a lot !